# Pass gridview template field text box id to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a ASP GridView in my webpage.

I have two template fields 1 textbox and 1 hyperlink.

If i click the hyperlink on that particular row I need to pass the corresponding textbox id in that particular row of gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Input">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" Text='<%# Eval("Input") %>' Width="200px" Height="70px" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="20px" Height="30px" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="12px" HorizontalAlign="Left"
    VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Verify">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" id="lnkView" onclick="GetResults('#<%= txtInput.ClientID %>')">
        <%#Eval("Verify")%>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="203px" Height="15px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="12px" HorizontalAlign="Left"
    VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I tried the below code but am getting error as name 'txtInput' does not exist in current context.

Javascript function

```
function GetResults(id) {

//My code using this textbox id

}
```

Please help on how to pass the text box id to javascript function on click of the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work (untested).

Following line, remove the # sign.

```
<a href="#" id="lnkView" onclick="GetResults('<%= txtInput.ClientID %>')">
```

Then your javascript:

```
function GetResults(id) {

var ctrlId = "[id$=" + id + "]"
var inputVal = $(ctrlId).val()

// do work

}
```